# error while sending text to div field in Safari using protractor

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, protractor, end-to-end

I've got a text area div field:

```
<div id="shortansweractivityId" class="shortanswerText ng-pristine ng-scope ng-isolate-scope ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-model="activity.answer" ng-if="isEditable" ng-focus="editing()" placeholder="Write here..." contenteditable="true" content-type="text"></div>
```

I'm able to use `sendKeys` in chrome using:

```
element(by.css('div#shortansweractivityId')).sendKeys('Test');
```

But when run the same in safari it errors out:

> UnknownError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'b.value.length')
>   (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 18 milliseconds Build info: version:
>   '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50' System
>   info: host: 'spatchamatla-mac.local', ip: '10.29.1.136', os.name: 'Mac
>   OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.3', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_45' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
>   Capabilities [{browserName=safari, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, version=8.0.6, cssSelectorsEnabled=true,
>   platform=MAC, secureSsl=true}] Session ID: null

Any suggestions?

Comment: why not just do
   ' element(by.id('shortansweractivityId').sendKeys('Test');'
 or does that nor work either?

Comment: @Sirk That doesn't work since Safari doesn't send Text to non input types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made it work in safari using `jquery` in `browser.executeScript()`.

Comment: could you post what you did exactly I'm trying to solve a similar problem but not well versed in jquery